# Replacing strings in expression Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a json file of fruits name which is like

```
[
    { "fruits" : "orange"
    },
    { "fruits" : "apple"
    }
]
```

and angular a normal

```
<div>{{fruits}}</div>
```

how do i change the strings in results to other words, example  i want the orange become orens and apple becomes apel without modifying json file. I have more than 30 words to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use-case for a pipe!

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'fruitMapper'})
export class FruitMapperPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    let result: string = value;
    // reassign result in a switch-block
    return result;
  }
}
```

And then in your template

```
<div>{{fruits | fruitMapper}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pipes`.

Check out the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)